# Create Dynamic theme with antd and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, themes, antd

i am creating a web application using `reactjs` and `antd`. Now i want to add a feature in which user will select color and all the primary color or web application will be changed. I did `searched` on google but most of the people says that its not possible using `antd` . Just wondering if someone has tried before or is it doable ?

Answer (score 0):

Antd supports [setting a custom theme](https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme#header). You should use that to generate a theme based on what color the user chooses.

Example `theme.js`:

```
module.exports = () => {
  return {
    'primary-color': '#1DA57A',
    'link-color': '#1DA57A',
    'border-radius-base': '2px',
  };
};
```

Comment: Also check out https://medium.com/@GeoffMiller/how-to-customize-ant-design-with-react-webpack-the-missing-guide-c6430f2db10f for more examples on theming